# Using modules in juypter lab with nbimport - Can Jupyter Lab can be used comfortably with modules?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-lab

My file structure:

```
app
- Main.ipynb
- Merger.ipynb
- Utils/common.ipynb
```

Main.ipynb:

```
import nbimporter
import Merger
Merger.merge(data)
```

Merger.ipynb:

```
import nbimporter
from Utils.common import parse_date
```

common.ipynb:

```
def parse_date(date_str):
bla
```

When typing 'Merger' the import is working and I can see the Merger's functions.
When I run `Merger.merge(data)`, i'm receving:

```
name 'parse_date' is not defined
```

However, when typing "parse_date" at Merger.ipynb, it recognizes it:

```
<function Utils.common.parse_date(date_str)>
```

​It seems like the imports doesn't go from file to file.

In addition, I need to restart the kernel from time to time for it to work.

How can I solve it?

Is it possible to use the Jupyter Lab like an IDE in a comfortable way?